# htaccess file with RewriteEngine On causes a 403

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, windows-server-2022

Windows Server 2022
Apache 2.4.57 x64

**httpd.conf** - relevant

```
<Directory />
    Options none
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DirectoryIndex index.html
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf** - relevant

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "c:/path/to/public_html"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "c:/path/to/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**files**

```
c:/path/to/public_html/index.php
c:/path/to/public_html/.htaccess
```

**.htaccess** - full

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

When `RewriteEngine Off` then https://www.example.com/ serves `index.php`

When `RewriteEngine On` then https://www.example.com/ results in a 403-Forbidden

Am I missing some obvious directive?

*Note: the behavior described above stays the same even if https://www.example.com/index.php is explicitly requested.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FIXED!**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "c:/path/to/public_html"
    
    ## NEW
    RewriteEngine On
    
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "c:/path/to/public_html">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        
        ## NEW
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Checking the logs revealed:

> [rewrite:error] AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions

RTFM'ing [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) reveals:

> To enable the rewrite engine in this context, you need to set "RewriteEngine On" and "Options FollowSymLinks" must be enabled.

Face, meet palm.

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks is the key